# temperatures files location

Tags: hardware, cpu

i want to know how to see temperature files in my Ubuntu system. I want to see the temperatures of cpu, graphics card, cheapset, etc. I know that they are somewhere on sys/class/(some people say at hwmon other to thermal). can you help me please? because I want to make a script for monitoring these temperatures but I don't want to install programs like psensors or acpi,etc...

Comment: See for yourself: `find /sys -name "temp"`.

Answer (score 4):

To see CPU temperature in in thousandths of a degree C, use the following command:

```
cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

To see detailed temperature information for other system temperature it is best to install `lm-sensors` using:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

Then you can run `sudo sensors-detect` to detect the sensors in your system and type **yes** at the end to have `sensors-detect` insert those modules into `/etc/modules`.

Run `service kmod start` to load these modules and run:

```
sensors
```

to get the temperature information for different parts (motherboard, coretemp, fan, etc.).

You can also redirect the output of `sensor` to a text file:

```
sensors >> /path/to/file.txt
```

Or watch it in real-time with:

```
watch -n 1 -d sensors
```

This updates it in every 1 second and highlights the difference from the second before.

More information is available in the [SensorInstallHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto).

Comment: thank you. that really works. can you tell me now how to see temperatures for graphics cards, cheapsets,motherboards,etc...?

Answer (score 0):

For systems with more than one temperature zone, you can see all at once with zone description. Copy and paste the command below into your terminal:

```
$ paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t
INT3400 Thermal  20000
SEN1             53000
SEN2             51000
SEN3             55000
SEN4             57000
B0D4             49000
pch_skylake      72500
x86_pkg_temp     51000
```